# Camel unmarshall jsonpath to pojo

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel, jsonpath

I'm trying to parse part of a message to a pojo so i can process it in java.
The message contains json, but i only need a part of it, so i tried to use jsonpath to pick the part of the json i need, but then i can't unmarshal, i also found a method to create the pojo directly from the jsonpath, but that returns null.

```
from(...)
.transform()
.jsonpath("@.data", false, POJO.class)
.process(...)
.end()
```

this leaves my POJO null.

```
from(...)
.transform.jsonpath("@.data")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, POJO.class)
.process(...)
.end()
```

This throws an exception:

```
Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-5CD9519Z86-1594305984947-0-330]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException - No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: {...}]
    at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.doHandleDelivery(RabbitConsumer.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.handleDelivery(RabbitConsumer.java:82)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {...}
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:216)
    at org.apache.camel.support.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:116)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

What would be the correct way to handle this.

Thanks in advance,

Bart Laeremans

Comment: I'll suggest to use ObjectMapper, like in the example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371785/how-do-i-parse-this-json-response-into-pojo

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to xpath which produces String, jsonpath library produces `LinkedHashMap`. Thus you're trying to unmarshal `LinkedHashMap` and not String.

e.g. original json: `{"books":{"book": {"name": "Some Book"}}}`
expected json: `{"name": "Some Book"}`
jsonpath expression: `"$.books.book"`

One would expect to get `{"name": "Some Book"}` so unmarshaller would produce instance
of BookDto. But its not the case.

You may pass result type into jsonpath so it would produce `BookDto` instead of `LinkedHashMap`. So won't need to unmarshal anymore.  (Like you already did)

The last one didn't work for me though.

```
String body = exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class);
BookDto book = JsonPath.parse(body).read("$.books.book", BookDto.class);
```

book is null :(

But this is JsonPath library issue and not Camel

Comment: I got it to work with jsonpath directly. By providing a custom configuration.  Configuration conf = Configuration
                .builder()
                .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider(objectMapper))
                .build();

        POJO p = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$.data", POJO.class);`  But how do i provide this configuration with Camel?

Comment: Thanks for the tip with mapping provider. That works for me as well. 
I am not sure if camel uses some kind of "jsonpath-default" bean which one could override. As a quick dirty hack i can image that you can create processor where you @autowire Configuration conf and then use it like you described. It won't be in the routebuilder itself but may be still better than nothing?